# AJAX/JQUERY check for blank value in field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Building a project where I am having to use AJAX (or is it jquery?) for first time and on a limited bases. I know almost nothing about AJAX/JQUERY so its a learn as i go thing for the moment.

I have 2 duplicate forms, 1 for creating new record and one for edit of record where PHP returns the existing values for the fields.

In the NEW RECORD form, there is a ajax call that is triggered when form object #dig6.blur() occurs, but the data for that field can be empty thus no trigger occurs.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{$("#dig6").blur(function(){ DO SOMETHING HERE } };
```

In the EDIT RECORD form, i need that ajax call to trigger on document ready **IF #dig6 has any value other than BLANK/NULL** - so my question is, is this below the correct AJAX method to check that value of #dig6 is not blank:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ if (!$("#dig6").val()== '') { DO SOMETHING HERE} };
```

Thanks

* Per a question:  #dig6 is a standard form input field with type set to TEXT

Comment: Have you tested it? Got expected result? You could eventually trim it if really needed

Comment: Other than missing a parenthesis at the end, the concept seems about right.

Comment: what is #dig6? is it an input or div or what?!

Comment: @A.Wolff not yet but will test it shortly, encountered this issue in the middle of larger edits, so need to complete the others changes before i can check this. Just wanted to know if the syntax I was using was the correct one or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A null field will always give you a falsy value. So shorten your code like the following and observe a truthy value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if( $("#dig6").val() ) {
        //dig6 is not null.
    }
}); //added parenth.
```

*This will not work with a multi-select. You'll have to check for an empty array in that case. `.val().length < 1`*

### Also, AJAX is a broad term. jQuery does implement a method(s) for ajax though...

Comment: Unless the element isn't an input, it will always return either a string, number, or array. never null. But the idea is sound, as an empty field will return `''` which is falsy (unless it's a select multiple, where it will return an empty array which is truthy)

Comment: @KevinB I don't know why you would use .val() on anything other than a form field.

Comment: Me either, but people do. I added that short line there to cover my bases. Can't say "always" without adding that exception.

Comment: @KevinB Never thought about a multi select.

Comment: I would test length, as one array will never be exactly equal to another unless it is a reference to the same array. But that's irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @James_1x0 thank you, i will test that shortly and respond with results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing jQuery with AJAX.

jQuery is a JavaScript library which allows you to a lot of stuff with less code than in plain JavaScript. Manipulating the DOM, for example, is much easier with jQuery.

AJAX, on the other hand, stands for Asynchronous JavaScript And XML. It's a technique that allows you to make calls to the server without having to reload the page so that the page becomes dynamic.

jQuery allows you to make AJAX calls easily, but i think you are trying to do another thing there.

try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var dig6 = $("#dig6");

    if (dig6.val()) {
        DO SOMETHING HERE
    }    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the short desc of AJAX vs JQUERY, your example has a slightly wrong idea, the the listener for BLUR() on the NEW RECORD form does a AJAX call to the server as you described., but on the EDIT RECORD form, the field in question #dig6 may already have a value that doesn't need to be changed, in that case i still need the AJAX call to occur - even though the field was not clicked into and back out of (i.e. BLUR() )

Comment: I've edited my answer. Is that what you are trying to achieve?